# GeoServer container need to test locally?

Tags: geoserver

GeoServer container need to test locally

I did some tests with geoserver and openlayers but it did not work with the layers I have on my machine. I did not need the container to use locally calling my WMS layers using openlayers. My javascript pages are in the openlayers folder on my C :/ are not in JSF project. 
My question is I need the container to use locally in my tests?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>

 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.2"></script>

 <script type='text/javascript'>


 var map;
 var mercatorProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
 var latLongProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
 var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                -51.2809219360352, -30.2445888519287,
                -51.0207977294922, -29.9661273956299
            );

 function init() {

  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element',{
    maxExtent: bounds,
    maxResolution:  0.0010877400636672,
    units: 'm',
    //allOverlays: true,
    projection: mercatorProjection,
    displayProjection: latLongProjection
 });


 var google_streets = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Ruas",
    {numZoomLevels: 20}
    );

var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
'Linhas Ônibus',
'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Teste/wms',
{layers: 'Teste:onibus', transparent: true},
{isBaseLayer: false,
    opacity: 0.7}
);


//Adiciona as camadas ao mapa
map.addLayers([google_streets, wms_layer]);


var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-51.22,-30.08); 
point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
    map.getProjectionObject()); 
map.setCenter(point, 10); 
 //Camada de controle que vai mostrar as camadas no mapa
 map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}));

 //Verifica se o mapa tem um ponto central e o extende a sua extensão máxima
 if(!map.getCenter()){
 map.zoomToMaxExtent();

 }
 }

 </script>
</head>

<body onload='init();'> <!-- Chama a função js init() --> 

<!--Elemento HTML onde o mapa é exibido -->
 <div id='map_element' style='width: 800px; height: 800px;'>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer can serve static pages by placing everything as needed inside the www directory which is part of the geoserver data directory itself.

See http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/staticfiles.html

Simone.

Comment: I have a "code" folder inside geoserver / datadir to the minimum openlayers files (. Metadata, img, theme) and my pages. Not installed geoserver in tomcat or jboss. And my pages do not show the WMS layers I have on my geoserver. My question is: my WMS layers can be not being shown because I have no container? 

I updated my code in question.

Comment: Not sure what this "code" folder is. Check my answer above, GeoServer can di simple serving for mashup but files needs to be placed in the right directory (the www ones) not anywhere in the data dir.

Comment: Ok, my pages are in C: \ Program Files \ GeoServer 2.4.5 data_dir \ \ www but still not open the WMS layers from my geoserver. I opened the examples that comes by default in geoserver (ol-demo) and also do not give anything. What could be wrong?